# Deleting an entry from Kafka state store

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

We have a stream processing application and in the stream, we extract an `id` and store it the state store. My use case is very simple, we store the id because, when we receive a request, we will be checking if the id is present in the store or not. The problem we have, all the event will have a unique id and the state store will eventually lead to out of memory. The data in the state store is not needed after some time.

1. Is there a way to have some configuration so, that the state clears the data after sometime based on the configuration?
2. Another approach would be to send a tombstone message with the key so that the entry will be deleted from the store. But, I feel, it somehow more work to do, as we have to manage to send another message to the topic and process it to delete the entry
3. How is the failure handling done in case if we going with the second approach?
4. Is there a way to manually delete an entry from the store. If so, what would be the impact of deleting the entry from the state store?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Not atm. (cf https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4212)
2. That's the correct approach.
3. No difference. If you do a `KeyValueStore#delete()` the entry is deleted from the store and a tombstone is written into the backing changelog topic.
4. What do you mean by queue?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 4) -> I meant the state store. I have updated the question. I think you have answered in point 3. Thanks again!!

Comment: If (4) is about deleting from the store, what you mean by (2) -- I thought (2) is about this?

Comment: I mean, if there is a way to do with method call something like `KeyValueStore#delete()`. Sorry for not being clear.

Comment: There is no other method. You need to call `#delete()`.